# Applying function to group of cells selected by cursor

Tags: excel, vba

I can add leading and trailing quotes to a cell that is selected with my cursor ( single cell ).

How do I apply the below function to all the selected cells if I select a group of cells with my cursor?

```
Sub AddQuotes()
ActiveCell.Value = ("*" & (ActiveCell.Value) & "*")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
Sub AddQuotes()
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng in Selection

    rng.Value = ("*" & (rng.Value) & "*")

Next rng

End Sub
```

You should however have a look into coding macrros without using selection or activating ranges.

Comment: there is no problem here with the use of `Selection`: OP has specifically selected some cells to operate on...

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to looping (though * is not a quote!):

```
Sub AddQuotes()
    With Selection
        .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate("INDEX(""*""&" & .Address & "&""*"",)")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your alternative. I wish I could mark both answers as valid.